# Django default value in in input field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I need to set a placeholder/default value for the input field below (the first field in the form)
I need to send the data ex_name.id in order to validate the form, which it does, but I want the information displayed in the field to be ex_name.exercise.

I was able to accomplish this in the option fields (fields 2 and 3), but not for the input field. If I make the input field an option field, it doesn't send the data when I submit it because the field is readonly and it has to stay readonly. value must be ex_name.id/ex_name.pk, but I don't want to display a number to the end user. How to I display different text there while still retaining value="{{ex_name.id}}"?

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

    <label for="exercise">Exercise</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_exercise" type="text" name="exercise" value="{{ex_name.id}}" required="" readonly>

    <label for="unit">Select Unit</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_unit" name="unit" value="">
        {% for unit in unit_list %}
      <option value="{{unit.id}}">{{unit.unit_name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_location" name="location" value="">
        {% for loc in locations %}
      <option value="{{loc.id}}">{{loc.location}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>


    <label for="quantity">Pax</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="" required="">

    <input class="btn btn-primary mt-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you generating input filed form django form , if yes then first add that code here. You can add attrs from form.

Comment: I ended up making it a hidden field and then creating a dummy field that displays the info I wanted.